# Is it better to do direct table loads in a high performance application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm using PostgreSQL in a Rails 3.2 application that receives updates from a third party all day long. Sometimes this third party will throw over 2,000 requests a minute at my application, each update consisting of a large XML file.

Right now I am storing basic information from each XML file into a table. Then, a background process picks up big chunks of data in that table and copies the data into a table using PostgreSQL's `COPY` feature.

Am I doing the right thing or the wrong thing here? This table that is the load target is also the major CRUD target of the UI. Does the `COPY` feature lock the entire table when the load happens, and should I be doing a bunch of inserts instead? I originally thought the inserts would be too expensive, but if the direct load locks the whole table then that's going to be a problem.

Comment: *Does the COPY feature lock the entire table when the load happens, and should I be doing a bunch of inserts instead?*. No, and no. See the documentation on explicit locking to see which commands take which locks. Or query `pg_locks`. (no time for a full answer right now.) Copy is very likely the right choice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` is the lowest level way to mass-insert records into PostgreSQL. I like your solution to post-process the records in a background job.

Alternatively, if you need to have performance and maintain some Rails/Ruby functionality, consider the 
[activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem. The gem will perform mass-insertions and allow ActiveRecord callbacks and validations to be used as needed. Even if you use this for post-processing of the bulk COPYed records, it may gain you a significant performance increase.

Here is a good article for using activerecord-import:
http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-import-millions-records-via-activerecord-within-minutes-not-hours/

This is what the Postgres team recommends for optimal import performance: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/populate.html